# BlocListener in BlocConsumer did not work, always build Builder at orElse state

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-bloc

I am new in both Dart and Flutter and still learning about this. I have problem at BlocConsumerWidget, i checked documentation and do not know what my mistake about this code. The problem is my BlocConsumer never print any state from BlocListener, the BlocConsumer directly trigger the BlocBuilder at orElse state.
Below is my code :

```
body: BlocProvider(
    lazy: false,
    create: (_) => getIt<RajaOngkirCubitCubit>(),
    child: BlocConsumer<RajaOngkirCubitCubit,RajaOngkirCubitState>(                   
      builder: (context, state) {
        return state.maybeMap(
          orElse: () => Container(child: Text("123"),),
          loading: (e) => Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
          error: (e) => buildErrorWidget(e),
          // onGetProvinceData: (e) {
          //   print(e.dataModel);
          // },
        );
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
        // TODO: implement listener
        state.maybeMap(
          orElse: () {
            print("orElse");
          },
          loading: (e) {
            print("Is Loading");
          },
          error: (e) {
            print(e.failed);
          },
          onGetProvinceData: (e) {
            print(e.dataModel);
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Here is my Cubit code

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_new_version_apps/domain/raja_ongkir/province/province_data_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_new_version_apps/domain/raja_ongkir/raja_ongkir_failed.dart';
import 'package:flutter_new_version_apps/domain/raja_ongkir/raja_ongkir_respository.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

part 'raja_ongkir_cubit_state.dart';
part 'raja_ongkir_cubit_cubit.freezed.dart';

@injectable
class RajaOngkirCubitCubit extends Cubit<RajaOngkirCubitState> {
  RajaOngkirCubitCubit(this._iRajaOngkir)
      : super(RajaOngkirCubitState.initial());

  IRajaOngkir _iRajaOngkir;

  void getProvinceDataFromInternet() async {
    emit(RajaOngkirCubitState.loading());
    try{
      final _result = await _iRajaOngkir.getProvinceData();
      _result.fold(
        (l) => emit(RajaOngkirCubitState.error(l)),
        (r) => emit(RajaOngkirCubitState.onGetProvinceData(r)),
      );

    } catch(e) {
      emit(RajaOngkirCubitState.error(RajaOngkirFailed().copyWith(description: e.toString())));
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my State code :

```
part of 'raja_ongkir_cubit_cubit.dart';

@freezed
class RajaOngkirCubitState with _$RajaOngkirCubitState {
  const factory RajaOngkirCubitState.initial() = _Initial;
  const factory RajaOngkirCubitState.loading() = _Loading;
  const factory RajaOngkirCubitState.error(RajaOngkirFailed failed) = _Error;
  const factory RajaOngkirCubitState.onGetProvinceData(List<ProvinceDataModel> dataModel) = _OnGetProvinceData;
}
```

Hope you guys can help me.
Thankyou

Comment: Can you please add the cubit and the state code here, this behaviour  can be checked based on this 2 files.

Comment: Okay, i will upload my Cubit and State code

Comment: Same problem. My listener never fires when I use sealed classes with @freezed package as state, as shown in the code above.